# Lato with font-weight 300 uses hairline instead of light variant

Tags: css, fonts

I've installed the Lato font (from http://www.latofonts.com) on my local machine. It contains several weight variants, such as Hairline, Thin, and Light.

When I create an HTML page and use CSS to select the Lato font, and set the font-weight to 300, the hairline variant is used.

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Using Google's web fonts, [thin is used for font-weight 100, light for weight 300](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato). On the other hand, when using the local fonts, hairline is used for all weights < 400, and there is no way to select the thin or light variants.

How do I use the thin or light variants locally (without Google web fonts), preferably by only changing the font-weight? Is there something wrong in my installation of the fonts, or in the usage?

Comment: Sorry, are you asking why Ubuntu is loading the wrong font? Because that's not related to CSS, or HTML, or even programming, and is probably a https://superuser.com question about "why is Ubuntu not using the right font".

Comment: I am having a similar problem. All variants are installed, and I can see "hairline", "thin", "light" etc in gnome-font-viewer. However, in Inkscape the only available font is "Light: Thin" and "Light Italic: Hairline Italic".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS weights are *not* a formal, real thing in font land, they're just a convention that only CSS uses, and has no effect on weights indicated by fonts as part of a font family. Those values are the `usWeightClass` in the `OS/2` table of OpenType fonts, and can be any number between 0 and 65355, with the numbers being purely based on what the designers/foundry means them to have.

So, looking at the Lato fonts, we see the following weights:

- Regular: OS/2.usWeightClass = 400
- Light: OS/2.usWeightClass = 300
- Thin: OS/2.usWeightClass = 275
- Hairline: OS/2.usWeightClass = 250

If you want the CSS to do "the right thing" when you set font weight in CSS, you have to map those *CSS font weight* to a real resource (which can have a completely different *actual font weight*) using @font-face rules:

```
/* Four different rules, for CSS weights 100, 200, 300, 400, same font name */

@font-face {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 100;
  src: local("Lato Hairline"),
       url("...latohairline.woff2") format(WOFF2);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 200;
  src: local("Lato Thin"),
       url("...latothin.woff2") format(WOFF2);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local("Lato Light"),
       url("...latolight.woff2") format(WOFF2);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local("Lato Regular"),
       url("...latoregular.woff2") format(WOFF2);
}
```

And now your CSS, when using the font family "Lato", will use the correct resource (according to you) based on the CSS font-weight property.

```
html, body {
  font-family: Lato;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-weight: 200;
}

p {
  font-weight: 400;
}

...
```

(**2019 edit**: changed the font-face to use woff2, because that's [the only format you should use by now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385)).