# @font face adding local font on mac only

Tags: css, fonts, localhost, font-face

I only want to add a local font to font face for use in a static HTML / CSS website. The font is located here: /Users/sdawes/Library/Fonts and my code is as follows, however it does not work. I am unsure whether my syntax is incorrect or am I missing something? Many thanks

```
@font-face {
font-family: CantoniPro;
src: local("/Users/sdawes/Library/Fonts/Brillant.ttf");
}

h2 {
font-family: "CantoniPro", "futura-pt", Serif;
font-weight: 500;
color: #2b292e;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to copy the file to the project folder and link to that file? Does that work?

Comment: yeah, I tired that and unfortunately it doesnt work.

Comment: Could you maybe convert it to .woff (see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration) and try that?