# Can't get the Bebas Neue Custom Font to work

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to get the Bebas Neue font to work, I've managed to convert my fonts into their respective types but whenever I load the font in the browser I get errors.

Firebug throws:

downloadable font: download failed

Chrome throws a 404 not found.

I initially had these in their own font folder, but I then decided to move the fonts to the same directory as the stylesheet I was using to try and rule out location problems.

This particular file is a SASS partial called _typography that lives in a folder called global this is the same folder I've directly placed all the fonts into as is.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url(BebasNeueRegular.eot);
    src: url(BebasNeueRegular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(BebasNeueRegular.woff) format('woff'),
         url(BebasNeueRegular.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(BebasNeueRegular.svg) format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Technical note: use WOFF/WOFF2, don't use any of the other formats - they were necessary in the past, but haven't been necessary for years now. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37091681/740553 for more detailed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `@font-face` matches your `font-family` use on CSS, either:

- `font-family: 'Bebas Neue';` on everything or:
- `font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';` on everything.

Like:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular';
    src: url(BebasNeueRegular.eot);
    src: url(BebasNeueRegular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(BebasNeueRegular.woff) format('woff'),
         url(BebasNeueRegular.ttf) format('truetype'),
         url(BebasNeueRegular.svg) format('svg');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Matches css use:

```
.selector {
  font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', sans-serif;
}
```

Or:

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
        src: url(BebasNeueRegular.eot);
        src: url(BebasNeueRegular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),
             url(BebasNeueRegular.woff) format('woff'),
             url(BebasNeueRegular.ttf) format('truetype'),
             url(BebasNeueRegular.svg) format('svg');

        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Matches:

```
.selector {
  font-family: 'Bebas Neue', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With a 404 Error - it's 98% going to be because of the path being wrong.

Just a thought - you mentioned that you moved them into a SASS partial? Can this folder be accessed from the site? From my experience, your SASS is going to compile into some sort of `public` directory.

In order to troubleshoot... theoretically, you should just be able to add `www.yourdomaincom/path-to-font/font.eot` and come up with a download file.

If you're not, then it really is an issue of the path being where the error lies. As far as why other fonts are working, I wouldn't be able to say without taking a better look at how you have your project set up.

Just my two cents worth to help you troubleshoot!

Comment: More explicitly: The path for url in the css font face declaration needs to match *as seen from the location of that css file*.