# How do I apply a local custom font to Stripe Elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, stripe.js

I am trying to use a font from a local `.otf` file inside my project's directory in order to style the text within the inputs of the credit card form provided by Stripe Elements.

As this is a React project, I have been making use of the `react-stripe-elements` library. I have been referencing the following docs in tandem:

- [`react-stripe-elements`](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#elements)
- [Stripe.js & Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-elements)

---

Here is where I attempt to use my desired font by passing it in through the `fonts` prop as specified in the `react-stripe-elements` docs:

```
<Elements
  fonts={[
    {
      family: 'geog',
      src: 'url(../../../shared/styles/fonts/Geogtq-Rg.otf)',
      style: 'normal',
      weight: '400',
    },
  ]}
>
  <StripeCCForm />
</Elements>
```

With this code, I get the following error:

`Invalid src value in font configuration: ../../../shared/styles/fonts/Geogtq-Rg.otf. URLs have to start with 'https://' or 'data:'`

---

I was under the impression that the `src` value could be a relative path to a local font, so I am quite confused as to why I am getting this error. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: On a fonts-on-the-web note, rather than a solution to what looks like a bundling problem, you don't want to use a raw .otf file, you want [woff or woff2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091681/740553)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this. I am having the same issue

Comment: @jgerstle, sorry for the slow response. I never did figure that out. Had to admit defeat, sadly.

Comment: Still no solution to this? I am getting the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Vue, and I originally had an answer here about having success with a `require` statement for `src`, but it turns out I didn't have to pass anything to `stripe.elements` at all. Instead, I have this:

```js
const stripeStyle = {
  style: {
    base: {
      fontFamily: 'Font-Name',
      // fontSize, etc. if applicable
    },
  },
};

const elements = stripe.elements();
this.cardNumber = elements.create('cardNumber', stripeStyle);
// etc.
```

Here's the important part: The value for `fontFamily` **matches the *filename*** I import through a Sass file. For this example, I would have:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "My Font";
  src: url("~@/assets/fonts/Font-Name.otf") format ("OpenType");
}
```

I'm not sure why this works, but hopefully it's possible for you to go about it this way.

Comment: Does this actually work outside of your machine? The stripe element uses an iFrame, which can't access the parent context's imported fonts. I have a feeling this might be working because there's a font installed locally on your machine with the font name, which is what the iFrame is referencing. This won't be the case for other users.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been addressed here: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/285

I was just searching for the same and it worked. It didn't work on local because of not having https, but works perfectly in the production.