# Unable to load @font-face fonts

Tags: css, apache, fonts, sass, directory-structure

My downloaded fonts are not appearing in Chrome. I'm using `scss` which is compiled to `css` via `gulp`.

If I go directly to

```
http://project-name.localhost/data/fnt/Shermlock.ttf
```

it downloads the font.

**_fonts.scss:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fishfingers';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("data/fnt/Fishfingers.ttf") format("ttf");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shermlock';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("data/fnt/Shermlock.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

Included in **main.scss** as such:

```
...
@import "base/fonts";
@import "global";
...
```

**HTML:**

```
...
span {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'Shermlock', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
...
.task {
    font-family: 'Fishfingers', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
...
```

**Project folder structure:**

```
project-name/
    build/
       index.html
       css/
           main.css <--- compiled scss
       data/
         fnt/
            Fishfingers.ttf
            Shermlock.ttf
    js/...
    sass/
       base/
           _fonts.scss
           ...
       _global.scss
       main.scss
```

**Apache setup:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName project-name.localhost
   DocumentRoot /Users/myname/Sites/project-name/build
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**EDIT**: looking at network requests, for let's say `Fishfingers`, I get the correct file as a `200` response:

```
Request URL: http://project-name.localhost/data/fnt/Fishfingers.ttf
```

Plugging in this url in the browser downloads the font file.

Response in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Comment: Is the file called Shermlock or Shermlocks?

Comment: @llobet that was a mistake in typing. It's Shermlock

Comment: fon't use system fonts, convert this to woff, and then use that, with the `format('woff')` option. [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that [font face](https://gist.github.com/jonathantneal/d0460e5c2d5d7f9bc5e6) mixin requires `format("ttf");` to be written out as `format("truetype");`.

And `format("otf");` would become `format("opentype");`, etc.

Comment: But way more important: don't use ttf / otf at all. Use WOFF instead, because ttf/otf are universal system fonts, and are treated as such. Convert your ttf or otf to WOFF format, and then use those, with `format('woff')`

Comment: Can you expand on "and treated as such"?

Comment: [I can](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37091681/740553), in [more than one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36110385/740553) in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Fishfingers';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("./data/fnt/Fishfingers.ttf") format("ttf");
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shermlock';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("./data/fnt/Shermlock.ttf") format("ttf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have rightly pointed out your css files are compiled into the 'main.css', however your path from the css file to the font location is incorrect as you first next to go up one level on the hierarchy. So amend the source url and prepend `../` to make `url("../data/fnt/Fishfingers.ttf")`