# Which Fontfile to use in a website?

Tags: css, performance, fonts, font-face, webfonts

Guys i am working on a custom project where i need font awesome 
But when checking fontawesome font files i can see they provide a lot of options

1. JS
2. SVG With JS
3. WebFonts

As for as i know i should use **WebFonts** but in that i can see there are lot of font file.

1. eot
2. svg
3. ttf
4. woff
5. woff2

is all the font formats are required  ?
Can we use only SVG ?

Actually i need my project in total of `2MB` if i add all the font files it taking too much space.

Comment: Basically it is there for browser support, it does not mean all users will have to load all those fonts, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002820/why-should-we-include-ttf-eot-woff-svg-in-a-font-face

Comment: @caiovisk thanks but i want to keep my project 2MB which means i can't pack full FontAwesome

Comment: woff seems to be the format you'd want to use. This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086562/what-kind-of-font-files-do-i-need-for-modern-browsers-android-and-ios / https://css-tricks.com/understanding-web-fonts-getting/

Comment: depending on the amount of icons you will actually be using, you may want to consider just using those individual icon .svg files directly (no font files)

Comment: @joknawe since my project is a framework for WP so i can't define which icons are required. so in fontawesome just the WOFF2 is good right ?

Comment: WOFF (not WOFF2) has more support across browsers.

Comment: @Joknawe. thanks so then i can include both WOFF & WOFF2 because it comes around 200KB for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of this posting your selected typeface, FontAwesome , contains 3,332 different glyphs. You are more than correct to assume that loading this file five times over will take up some serious system resources.

**However…**

Often when using a webfont for icons, we only use a portion of the many icons defined in the font. If you are *only* using three or four glyphs from FontAwesome, then loading those five times should be a light-as-a-feather job for your system.

How to do this? Use a font-subsetting service. Free and easy-to-follow instructions on their sites. There are several, but personally I've had success with fontello: http://fontello.com

I have subsetted (verb?) about 20-25 icons from FontAwesome (more than I needed) to provide simple icons on my site, and the file sizes are under 60KB, *collectively.*

And of course, the reason we load these five times over? To maximize cross-browser compatibility. Plain and simple. This does it.

Comment: Since i am working on a custom WP Framework i can't force user to use less glyps

Comment: @Varun Sridharan Are you saying that you can choose the font format, but not the font itself? (Or as joknawe wisely suggests, an image-based solution.)

Comment: i am not sure. what you mean. this is my framework ( http://github.com/wponion/dev) in which i would like to include not only fontawesome but also some top icon fonts. but the size dose matters me.