# Failed to decode downloaded font - ember-cli (3.7.1)

Tags: fonts, font-face, ember-cli, google-material-icons, ember-addon

I'm facing this font decoding issue after I deploy ember cli app to heroku. It works fine in my localhost. I'm using @font-face rule for custom font and ember addon for material-icons(ember-material-icons). Any helps would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: OTS is being pretty clear here: that font is not actually a legal font because its encoded `version` field is wrong. So redownload the font from the official source, and use that (also [don't use ttf or otf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385)).

Comment: But whats wrong with material icon fonts? that also not loading.

Comment: what do you mean "what's wrong"? It literally tells you: OTS (the opentype sanitizer) checked the file you thought was a font, and the bytes that cover the `version` tag that all opentype fonts have, is not set to a legal value, so it can't be loaded as a font. Maybe your download got corrupted, maybe your OS "fixed" the byte ordering and so broke the font: get a new copy of that font and things should work. And ideally, get the font _on the server_ (curl or npm install via ssh for instance) instead of copying it over, to prevent byte reordering during copy.

Comment: I think the issues probably has to do with the double `assets/assets/` URL. Try copying that full font URL into your browser. I would guess you will not download the font itself. Instead you will see your ember app or a 404 page. This could also be an issue of heroku blocking the route or your deployment process not including the file. Could you add your font-face rule to the question as well?