# Font-Face works locally, but not on staging server

Tags: fonts, font-face, local, staging

Font face works perfectly on my local machine, and when i am viewing the staging site on my local machine, but when viewed on my phone or other computers the font doesn't load correctly.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: '../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi';
    src:    url('../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi.eot');
    src:    url('../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi.svg#LubalinGraphStd-Demi') format('svg'),
            url('../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi.woff2') format('woff2');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Heres the staging link: http://tpo.tmwlsh.co.uk
username: tpo, password: tpo.

Comment: Don't use this syntax, this is an block of code for loading fonts from 2012, when the webfont landscape was radically different, and makes no sense today. On the modern web, [just use woff/woff2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385) and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Your `font-family` name looks suspicious in your `@font-face`:

```
    font-family: '../fonts/LubalinGraphStd-Demi';
```

Looks like you accidentaly used the filename here, instead of a normal name. You're applying `font-family: LubalinGraphStd-Demi` in your elements, so if you change it to:

```
    font-family: 'LubalinGraphStd-Demi';
```

It should be fixed.

On a different note, you're using some ancient font formats there. Are you sure you need to support acient first gen iPads or iPhones with iOS3, or IE8 and older?