# import Font .woff not work Referered by css file - Work good on Localhost but didnt in anther host

Tags: html, css, fonts, css-selectors

I was build the site on localhost then uploaded the CSS + JS + fonts in the host
and link it with HTML 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.xathena.store/PublicKeys/PublicKey-SH33NZ0_XHvyyHr6Vc2iJd1mFfmHamwm6r1jKi4l/lib/styles/signin.css">`
The CSS works good 
but should the css contains

```
@font-face {
    font-family: pp-sans-small-light;
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_light.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_light.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/p_small_light.woff) format("woff"), url(../fonts/p_small_light.svg) format("svg")
}

@font-face {
    font-family: pp-sans-small-regular;
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_regular.eot);
    src: url(../fonts/p_small_regular.eot) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/p_small_regular.woff) format("woff"), url(../fonts/p_small_regular.svg) format("svg")
}

* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

@media (max-width:767px) {
    * {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none
    }
}

html {
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #2c2e2f;
    font-family: pp-sans-small-regular, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 93.75%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%
}
```

should import fonts but give me error 
this photo from the Google Chrome debugger

Note the font path is correct and the fonts uploaded in the same host too

It is work when was

I mean when it was work on localhost but I want to upload it on the host

Dont give me Response / Preview on the debugger

Comment: Well the mime-type for the font is correct (application/font-woff). Please post a link to an example page.

Comment: [Don't use eot, and _especially_ don't use SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration/36110385#36110385). Remove those, just use the WOFF version, and see what the browser does. And make sure to look at the dev tools console and network tabs because if you messed up the URLs, they will tell you that.