# Why did the server send me a font that is already installed on my machine?

Tags: python, html, css, django, fonts

I am new to web development and I am trying to make a simple web game using python 3.7 with django as web framework combined with the [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package for using web sockets.

I am trying to use custom fonts for the game UI. I used the css `local()` function to make sure the fonts aren't sent if the client has them already installed on his system as it says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face):

> It's common to use both `url()` and `local()` together, so that the user's
>   installed copy of the font is used if available, falling back to
>   downloading a copy of the font if it's not found on the user's device.

However, it seems that the django development server sends me those fonts although I already have them installed on my machine.

Here's my html templates and css:

**core/templates/core/base.html:**

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    {% if title %}
        <title>Stratego - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Stratego</title>
    {% endif %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "core/css/style.css" %}">
</head>

<body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

**core/templates/core/game.html:**

```html
{% extends "core/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1 class="main-header">Hello</h1>
<div class="regular-text">Hello</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**core/static/core/css/style.css**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

/* ########## Alegreya ########## */

/* Regular */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
    src: local("Alegreya"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/Alegreya-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
/* end Regular */

/* Bold */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
    src: local("Alegreya"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/Alegreya-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
}
/* end Bold */

/* Italic */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
    src: local("Alegreya"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/Alegreya-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
    src: local("Alegreya"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/Alegreya-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: oblique;
}
/* end Italic */

/* Bold-Italic */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
    src: local("Alegreya"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/Alegreya-BoldItalic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
    src: local("Alegreya"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/Alegreya-BoldItalic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
}
/* end Bold-Italic */

/* ########## AlegreyaSC ########## */

/* Regular */
@font-face {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    src: local("Alegreya SC"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
}
/* end Regular */

/* Bold */
@font-face {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    src: local("Alegreya SC"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
}
/* end Bold */

/* Italic */
@font-face {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    src: local("Alegreya SC"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    src: local("Alegreya SC"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-Italic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-style: oblique;
}
/* end Italic */

/* Bold-Italic */
@font-face {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    src: local("Alegreya SC"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    src: local("Alegreya SC"),
        url("/static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-BoldItalic.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: oblique;
}
/* end Bold-Italic */

.main-header {
    font-family: "AlegreyaSC";
    font-weight: bold;
}

.regular-text {
    font-family: "Alegreya";
}
```

The fonts are located in `core/static/core/fonts`.

When I start the django development server by running `python manage.py runserver` and go to the url in my browser, I get the correct results, but in the terminal I get this output:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 17 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
July 04, 2019 - 17:16:31
Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'stratego.settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.2.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
HTTP GET / 200 [0.02, 127.0.0.1:60158]
HTTP GET /static/core/css/style.css 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:60158]
HTTP GET /static/core/fonts/AlegreyaSC-Bold.ttf 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:60158]
HTTP GET /static/core/fonts/Alegreya-Regular.ttf 200 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:60159]
Not Found: /favicon.ico
HTTP GET /favicon.ico 404 [0.00, 127.0.0.1:60158]
```

I am not using a database yet so the migrations are not important.
From the output, you can see that the server sent the fonts to the client, but they're already installed on my machine, so why did it send them?
I don't think I made a mistake in the naming (In my computer settings these fonts are called "Alegreya" and "Alegreya SC").

Did I misunderstand how the `local()` function works in css or I did something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

<sub>PS: I am using python 3.7.3 with django 2.2.2 and firefox 67.0.4 on windows 10 if that's important to note.</sub>

Comment: Try specifying the exact name? - src: local("Alegreya Regular") and/or src: local("Alegreya-Regular")

Comment: Don't use `local()`, and don't use `ttf`/`otf`. `local()` _cannot_ check whether the font you need is the font that's actually installed, all it can do is look at the font family name, which is _not_ good enough (if you're using `San Frasisco`, the sleek Apple version, and someone has `San Fransisco`, the all over the place fantasy font, what do you think will happen?). And don't use universal system fonts, [pack it for web delivery as woff2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/#36110385) with woff fallback only (because no browser needs that old format other than IE11)

Comment: And on a django templating note, no need to duplicate the title tag, you can put your conditional in the title element itself `<title>Stratego{% if title %} - {{ title }}{% endif %}</title>`

Comment: @Mike So you're saying I should always send the client the fonts even if they already have them installed on their system? Also, thanks for the advice on the django template. Looks cleaner.

Comment: Correct: you should send them the assets you need your website to load, with sensible cache headers, so that the browser can cache the font so they only need to download it once. And by using WOFF2, which allows per table compression, and can remove a lot of data that otf/ttf _must_ have, and for the web is _100% irrelevant_, you typically send fonts that are many times smaller than even a single hero banner JPG

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got rid of the `local()` and converted the ttf's into woff2 and woff (woff is a fallback).