# Celtic font - eot, woff, ttf - webfont

Tags: wordpress, fonts, webfonts, woff, eot

I have to say at once that I am no expert, so apologies for asking for your help as follows:

1. I have been using "Celtic (Plain):001.001" font on a Wordpress website for several years without any problems.
2. Now there is a problem - on inspecting the website there is an error telling me this:
   "downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Celtic (Plain):001.001" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:2): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: https://xxxxx/wp-content/themes/responsive-childtheme-master/fonts/Celtic.ttf"
3. In my child theme's stylesheet I have this:
   "@font-face {font-family:"Celtic (Plain):001.001";src:url("https://xxxx/wp-content/themes/responsive-childtheme-master/fonts/Celtic.eot?") format("eot"),url("https://xxxx/wp-content/themes/responsive-childtheme-master/fonts/Celtic.woff") format("woff"),url("https://xxxx//wp-content/themes/responsive-childtheme-master/fonts/Celtic.ttf") format("truetype"),url("https://xxxxx/wp-content/themes/responsive-childtheme-master/fonts/Celtic.svg#Celtic") format("svg");font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}"
4. In my fonts folder I have these fonts: Celtic.eot, Celtic.svg, Celtic.ttf, Celtic.woff.
5. I have this error on one website. I also have another testing Wordpress website elsewhere and there is no problem with the font.
6. So I am not sure if this is due to the way I installed the font or CORS policy scripting.

I saw a similar topic here [eot, woff fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36105194/are-eot-ttf-and-svg-still-necessary-in-the-font-face-declaration) - I assume this is not the same thing?

I sincerely hope you will be able to help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by my host provider - there was a setting that was not configured on their panel for the CORS rule to work.